# Unable to connect wireless networks requiring password

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager

I am able to connect to wifi networks that don't require password.
But when I try to connect to a network that requires password, the password is not asked, Network Manager just tries to connect and of course it fails.

This is the log from /var/log/syslog:

```
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625898.1943] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'true_home2G_b68' (ea2f25dd-98bd-4e72-b660-5ac56c683519)
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625898.1944] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="ea2f25dd-98bd-4e72-b660-5ac56c683519" name="true_home2G_b68" pid=2168 uid=1000 result="success"
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625898.1945] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625898.1946] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625898.1951] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625898.1953] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'true_home2G_b68' has security, but secrets are required.
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625898.1953] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
NetworkManager[936]: <warn>  [1495625923.2170] device (wlp2s0): No agents were available for this request.
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625923.2171] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
gnome-session[1940]: (nm-applet:2168): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625923.2174] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[936]: <warn>  [1495625923.2184] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'true_home2G_b68'
NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1495625923.2199] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
kernel: [32456.473864] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

I don't know if it matters, I think this problem started after installation of [anbox](https://anbox.io/). After that, in ifconfig results, wlp2s0 was replaced by another entry (anboxlo if I remember correctly). Now I removed anbox and tried to put back the old settings, searched for the errors in output... but no success.

Please help me here. I will be available to give more information as required.

---

EDIT 1 to add information required by @George in comment:

Result of `$ less /var/log/syslog | grep -i wpa`:

```
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 dbus[888]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1' unit='wpa_supplicant.service'
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 dbus[888]: [system] Successfully activated service 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1'
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 NetworkManager[2619]: <info>  [1495977085.7349] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
May 28 15:11:25 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp2s0 flags: No such device
May 28 15:11:33 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
May 28 15:13:07 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
May 28 15:13:07 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
May 28 15:13:24 dv-XPS-15-9550 NetworkManager[2755]: <info>  [1495977204.9381] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
May 28 15:13:24 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
May 28 15:13:24 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
May 28 15:13:24 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlp2s0: -16 (Device or resource busy)
May 28 15:13:24 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlp2s0
May 28 15:13:24 dv-XPS-15-9550 wpa_supplicant[2633]: P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
```

(Network Manager seems to not be running after system boot. I run these commands: `$ sudo service network-manager restart` at 15:11:25, `$ sudo service network-manager stop` at 15:13:07 and `$ sudo service network-manager start` at 15:13:24)

---

EDIT 2 for more requested information:

```
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files --type=service | grep enabled

accounts-daemon.service                    enabled 
anacron-resume.service                     enabled 
anacron.service                            enabled 
autovt@.service                            enabled 
avahi-daemon.service                       enabled 
bluetooth.service                          enabled 
brltty.service                             enabled 
cron.service                               enabled 
cups-browsed.service                       enabled 
cups.service                               enabled 
dbus-org.bluez.service                     enabled 
dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service         enabled 
dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service enabled 
dbus-org.freedesktop.thermald.service      enabled 
display-manager.service                    enabled 
dns-clean.service                          enabled 
friendly-recovery.service                  enabled 
getty@.service                             enabled 
gpu-manager.service                        enabled 
lightdm.service                            enabled 
mariadb.service                            enabled 
ModemManager.service                       enabled 
mysql.service                              enabled 
mysqld.service                             enabled 
networking.service                         enabled 
NetworkManager-wait-online.service         enabled 
pppd-dns.service                           enabled 
resolvconf.service                         enabled 
rsyslog.service                            enabled 
snapd.autoimport.service                   enabled 
snapd.service                              enabled 
snapd.system-shutdown.service              enabled 
syslog.service                             enabled 
systemd-timesyncd.service                  enabled 
thermald.service                           enabled 
ufw.service                                enabled 
unattended-upgrades.service                enabled 
ureadahead.service                         enabled 
whoopsie.service                           enabled

$ iw list | grep -i p2p

 * P2P-client
 * P2P-GO
 * P2P-device
 * start_p2p_device
 * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
 * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
 * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
```

---

EDIT 3 after enabling Network Manager service:

```
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files --type=service | grep enabled
accounts-daemon.service                    enabled 
anacron-resume.service                     enabled 
anacron.service                            enabled 
autovt@.service                            enabled 
avahi-daemon.service                       enabled 
bluetooth.service                          enabled 
brltty.service                             enabled 
cron.service                               enabled 
cups-browsed.service                       enabled 
cups.service                               enabled 
dbus-org.bluez.service                     enabled 
dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service         enabled 
dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service enabled 
dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service enabled 
dbus-org.freedesktop.thermald.service      enabled 
display-manager.service                    enabled 
dns-clean.service                          enabled 
friendly-recovery.service                  enabled 
getty@.service                             enabled 
gpu-manager.service                        enabled 
lightdm.service                            enabled 
mariadb.service                            enabled 
ModemManager.service                       enabled 
mysql.service                              enabled 
mysqld.service                             enabled 
network-manager.service                    enabled 
networking.service                         enabled 
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service          enabled 
NetworkManager-wait-online.service         enabled 
NetworkManager.service                     enabled 
pppd-dns.service                           enabled 
resolvconf.service                         enabled 
rsyslog.service                            enabled 
snapd.autoimport.service                   enabled 
snapd.service                              enabled 
snapd.system-shutdown.service              enabled 
syslog.service                             enabled 
systemd-timesyncd.service                  enabled 
thermald.service                           enabled 
ufw.service                                enabled 
unattended-upgrades.service                enabled 
ureadahead.service                         enabled 
whoopsie.service                           enabled
```

$ iw list | grep -i p2p
(same)

Also let me add that now when I try to connect to a wifi with password I get this error message in popup:

> ## Connection failure
>
> **Connection activation failed**
>
> (2) Active connection removed before it was initialized

Comment: One think I noticed is that I have no file /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf which I see that should exist in many places. I do have thse files in /etc/wpa_supplicant: action_wpa.sh, functions.sh, ifupdown.sh

Comment: Here it is a full report for my network connections (based on https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info):
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24656887/

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl restart dbus` and if it fails restart the system

Comment: @George I have tried that:
`$ sudo systemctl restart dbus` and I receive the message `Failed to restart dbus.service: Operation refused, unit dbus.service may be requested by dependency only.
See system logs and 'systemctl status dbus.service' for details.` ... I checked systemctl status and logs but nothing seems relevant (please tell me if you want me to detail here that information), from what I understand it's simply not allowed to restart this service. I have restarted the system many many times but the problem always persists.

Comment: Please run `less /var/log/syslog | grep -i wpa` and post any results

Comment: I've added that information in EDIT @George. Previous logs were older repititions of same messages from older sessions, if I really should put "any" results please tell me :) and by the way, thanks for helping me here!

Comment: Also post this: `sudo systemctl list-unit-files  --type=service | grep enabled`

Comment: Also add this: `iw list | grep -i p2p`

Comment: I've searched for more info about first error, then I got [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1439771) and from reply #20 I got [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1654730). It mentions my laptop, XPS-15-9550 and recommends to update BIOS. I suppose it wont harm to do it...

Ops, now I saw your last two comments, I will proceed as you requested.

Comment: @George I've updated the question with requested information (EDIT 2).

Comment: Your `NetworkManager.service ` doesn't appear to be enabled, Please enable with `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager`, then `sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager`

Comment: Done @George in EDIT 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59451/discussion-between-george-and-dxvargas).

Comment: @George, `sudo apt build-dep network-manager` didn't resolve the issue. Same errors continue.

Comment: More information: I've updated BIOS, without effects here. When I boot from a pen drive, I can use every network, also with password!

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. FAIL!!! But now connection problems are gone.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by fail! Being expecting you in chat

Comment: @George sorry I didn't knew you were expecting me in chat. I posted here the comment about your instructions and was waiting for a reply. When I say it's a fail, it is because it shouldn't be needed to reinstall the system from scratch to solve a very precise error in a component. The fail is mine, for sure, and maybe (or maybe not) from Ubuntu. I really appreciate your efforts to help me here! Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome sorry you had to re-install. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

the keyring daemon is probably not running. you can check if it is enabled in autostart applications, look for "Gnome keyring"

also, i think `consolekit` should be running as a service

Comment: I've checked, keyring is running (`$ ps aux | grep keyring`). Information I've got ([like here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/do-i-really-need-console-kit-4175491653/)) for consolekit is that it isn't neither required nor very trustful.